# How to change an object's returned string when binded to DataGridView?

Tags: c#, data-binding

I have an object, Pattern, that contains a list of doubles. These objects are stored in a DataTable. When bound to a DataGridView, how do I specify within the Pattern class how these are displayed?

Edit:

Here's some more explanation.
I have a class like this:

```
class Pattern
{
    double[] arr;
    public Pattern(double[] a)
    {
        arr = a;
    }
}
```

Pattern objects are stored in a DataTable:

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dt.Columns.Add("Patterns", typeof(Pattern));
```

This DataTable is then bound to some DataGridView. However, the Pattern objects are obviously not displayed correctly. I want them to displayed as some string I specify within the Pattern class. In C++, I would do something similar by overloading the output operator. Is there a way to do this in C# with DataGridViews?

Comment: any code or more explanation please

Comment: @RohitVats I added further explanation.

Comment: "Obviously not displayed properly" isn't quite obvious from here... what do you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the `ToString()` method in your `Pattern` class:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Join(",", arr);
}
```